# Error get remote image - WooCommerce Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I wrote a php script to import products from xml to woocommerce.

It worked great until now, when sistem give me back

[woocommerce_product_image_upload_error] error 400 – Error get remote image

I doesn t changed nothing in my code, it started alone.

Can anyone suggest me something?

I saw only that now accept only still uploaded images on wordpress media, and not the pictures taken from url (which it ran).

Comment: What is the URL? Does it still exist? Has the site/server gone away or the domain expired?

Comment: @Andy the url is:
http://www.gallianiduemila.it/wp-content/uploads/ahrwp/img/011/00000000000000001140_art_icol_12742.jpg

Comment: try this simple free plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/

Comment: my script is correct. It works great. It give me back this error only on one server. maybe there aren t sufficient resources on this server?... and i can t retrieve image?

Comment: Another one wp problem without solution... Great

Comment: I'm receiving this too, and my URL is in format:
`https://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/files/f4b/f4bc7939358d3ab7d79751761c0b11b0?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22mockup-650c3c18.jpg%22&AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Expires=1549450399&Signature=CAe%2BDqzTh8g5bmegSg6huYhZP4k%3D`
Maybe it's not being decoded correctly or something.

Comment: @MarcoFerretti, was this ever solved?